# Distributing Bath money over n people

Tags: haskell, combinatorics

I found the following problem online and was intrigued to solve this in Haskell.

> Given money X Baht and N people where we will distribute the money as
> follows... 1st turn: Give the first person 1 Baht, the second person
> gets 2 Baht, ..., and the Nth person gets N Baht. If the money (X -
> distributed money) is still remaining, then we will distribute it
> again. So... 2nd turn: Give the first person 2 Baht, the second person
> gets 3 Baht, ..., and the Nth person gets N+1 Baht. 3rd turn: Give the
> first person 3 Baht, the second person gets 4 Baht, ..., and the Nth
> person gets N+2 Baht.
>
> We will distribute money until it runs out. Then the output is an
> array of money that each person gets.
>
> For example: Input: x = 21 (Baht) and n = 5 (as a head count). 1st
> turn, each person will receive money as `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` 2nd turn,
> each person will receive money as `{2, 3, 1, 0, 0}`
>
> ∴ In the end, the output will be `{3, 5, 4, 4, 5}`

The question is how to implement this in Haskell, and preferably in *O(n)* time.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem we have to solve is knowing how many rounds we can fill completely, and how many Bath's we still need to distribute. We can express this as a sum expression with:

[image: k=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}{i+j}=\frac{m\cdot{}n\cdot(m+n)}{2}]

we can use this for the number of Bath's *k* to get the number of full rows with *M*:

[image: M=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8\cdot k\cdot n+n^4}-n^2}{2\cdot n}\right\rfloor]

If we only consider the *full* rounds, the first person will have *M×(M+1)/2*, the second *M×(M+1)/2+M*, and the *j*-th person *M×(M+1)/2+j×M*.

It is possible that there are still Bath's left, indeed, after the *M* full rounds, there are still *r = K - M×n×(m+n)/2* left, these are then distributed in the final round. Here *min(M+1, r)*, the second one *min(M+2, max(r-M-1, 0))*, the third one *min(M+3, max(r-2×M-3, 0))*, etc.

If we thus assume that all the arithmetic operations run in *O(1)*, then the following algorithm works in *O(n)*:

```
distribute :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
distribute n k = zipWith (+) (take n [n0, n0 + m ..]) (final (m + 1) r)
  where
    m = (floor (sqrt (fromIntegral (8 * k * n + n * n * n * n) :: Double)) - n * n) `div` (2 * n)
    r = k - (m * n * (m + n) `div` 2)
    n0 = m * (m + 1) `div` 2

final :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
final i j = k : final (i + 1) (j - k)
  where
    k = min i j
```

We can inspect the result by enumerating over the possible baths, for example with four persons:

```
Main> mapM_ print (map (distribute 4) [0 .. 50])
[0,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0]
[1,1,0,0]
[1,2,0,0]
[1,2,1,0]
[1,2,2,0]
[1,2,3,0]
[1,2,3,1]
[1,2,3,2]
[1,2,3,3]
[1,2,3,4]
[2,2,3,4]
[3,2,3,4]
[3,3,3,4]
[3,4,3,4]
[3,5,3,4]
[3,5,4,4]
[3,5,5,4]
[3,5,6,4]
[3,5,7,4]
[3,5,7,5]
[3,5,7,6]
[3,5,7,7]
[3,5,7,8]
[3,5,7,9]
[4,5,7,9]
[5,5,7,9]
[6,5,7,9]
[6,6,7,9]
[6,7,7,9]
[6,8,7,9]
[6,9,7,9]
[6,9,8,9]
[6,9,9,9]
[6,9,10,9]
[6,9,11,9]
[6,9,12,9]
[6,9,12,10]
[6,9,12,11]
[6,9,12,12]
[6,9,12,13]
[6,9,12,14]
[6,9,12,15]
[7,9,12,15]
[8,9,12,15]
[9,9,12,15]
[10,9,12,15]
[10,10,12,15]
[10,11,12,15]
[10,12,12,15]
[10,13,12,15]
```